# Is there a way to schedule something that unlocks Windows and performs a task?

Tags: windows, automation, scheduled-tasks, automatic-logon

Is there a way to setup a scheduled task that, at a given time each day, performs the following steps:

- Unlocks Windows
- Performs a series of clicks and drag+drop actions with the mouse cursor.

What I'm trying to do is have my computer record a program that's live streamed every morning, way earlier than I want to wake up myself. So it needs to unlock the computer, mute it (this step's not critical as I could just mute it the night before), open a browser to a certain website, click a "record" button in the system tray, then select the region in the browser where the video is playing.

Comment: You're likely to get a better response if you share what you've already explored and tried, and any specific issues that are the obstacle.

Comment: Doing what you've defined would be extremely complicated, but you could make it much simpler by setting things up before you go to bed.  Open the website, setup screen capture, etc., so you're just scheduling the start button.